# ListOfFigures in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm trying to put the List of Figures into the toc, but everything I tried does not work.

My main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[
        a4paper,
        11pt,
        parskip=half-,
        oneside,
        listof=totoc,
        bibtotocnumbered,
        headings=big,
        appendixprefix=true
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}


% Bearbeitungsdatum
\date{\today}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{interfaces}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\addto\captionsngerman{\let\appendixpagename\appendixname}

\begin{document}    
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\PartEinleitung
Some beginning text
\tocsetup{
    title/font = \huge\color{blue},
    part/font = \large\bfseries\color{blue},
    part/number/width=8mm,
    part/number/after = .,
    chapter/number/after = .,
    chapter/indent=8mm,
    chapter/number/width=8mm,   
    section/number/after = .,
    section/indent = 16mm,
    section/number/width=10mm,
    subsection/indent=26mm,
    subsection/number/after = .,
    subsection/number/width=10mm,
    subsubsection/indent=36mm,
    subsubsection/number/after = .,
    subsubsection/number/width=13mm
}
\listofsetup{lot}{
    parskip=0cm,
    title/font = \huge\color{blue},
    table/number/after = .,
    table/number/width=13mm,
}   
\listofsetup{lof}{
    parskip=0cm,
    title/font = \huge\color{blue},
    figure/number/after = .,    
    figure/number/width=13mm
}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{pdfinhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\label{LastPageEinleitung}
\clearpage
\cleardoublepage

\PartHauptteil
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Some Text included by "include commands"
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\printbibliography
\label{LastPageHauptteil}
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{Alph}
\PartAppendix
\appendix
\begin{appendices}
    \label{LastPageAppendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The Bibliograpie shows up in the toc, but not the list of figures...
\listoffigures does also not create a chapter or something like that, since the \headmark does not change on the page with the list of figures.

Comment: Use `bibliography=numbered` instead the deprecated `bibtotocnumbered` to avoid a warning and the switch to `version=first`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `titles` option of the `tocloft` package. It solves both
issues in one shot. BUT: It would be better if you set up your document using the KOMA-script interfaces to change title formats and ToCs. This way you wouldn't have such issues.

```
\documentclass[
        a4paper,
        11pt,
        parskip=half-,
        oneside,
        listof=totoc,
        bibtotocnumbered,
        headings=big,
        appendixprefix=true
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}


% Bearbeitungsdatum
\date{\today}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{interfaces}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}
\addto\captionsngerman{\let\appendixpagename\appendixname}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\begin{document}    
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
Some beginning text
\tocsetup{
    title/font = \huge\color{blue},
    part/font = \large\bfseries\color{blue},
    part/number/width=8mm,
    part/number/after = .,
    chapter/number/after = .,
    chapter/indent=8mm,
    chapter/number/width=8mm,   
    section/number/after = .,
    section/indent = 16mm,
    section/number/width=10mm,
    subsection/indent=26mm,
    subsection/number/after = .,
    subsection/number/width=10mm,
    subsubsection/indent=36mm,
    subsubsection/number/after = .,
    subsubsection/number/width=13mm
}
\listofsetup{lot}{
    parskip=0cm,
    title/font = \huge\color{blue},
    table/number/after = .,
    table/number/width=13mm,
}   
\listofsetup{lof}{
    parskip=0cm,
    title/font = \huge\color{blue},
    figure/number/after = .,    
    figure/number/width=13mm
}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\label{LastPageEinleitung}
\clearpage
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
Some Text included by "include commands"
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\label{LastPageHauptteil}
\cleardoublepage
\Blinddocument

\pagenumbering{Alph}
\appendix
\begin{appendices}
    \label{LastPageAppendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

How you could get your stuff done using only KOMA-script:

```
\documentclass[
        a4paper,
        11pt,
        parskip=half-,
        oneside,
        listof=totoc,
        bibliography=numbered,
        headings=big,
        appendixprefix=true
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\setkomafont{partentry}{\large\bfseries\color{blue}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocnumwidth=8mm
  ]{part}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocindent=8mm
    ,tocnumwidth=8mm
  ]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocindent=16mm
    ,tocnumwidth=10mm
  ]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocindent=26mm
    ,tocnumwidth=10mm
  ]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocindent=36mm
    ,tocnumwidth=13mm
  ]{subsubsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry
  [%
    numwidth=13mm
  ]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry
  [%
    numwidth=13mm
  ]{tocline}{table}

\BeforeTOCHead{\addtokomafont{chapter}{\huge\color{blue}}}

\begin{document}    
\pagenumbering{Roman}
Some beginning text
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\part{FOOOBAR}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Some Text included by "include commands"
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\Blinddocument
\captionof{figure}{foobar}
\captionof{table}{foobar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I'll keep it in mind for the next project!