# How to force Latex to keep TOC lines within page margins?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, interfaces

I've a line in my toc that is a bit too long, but not as long as latex would recognize it to make a new line:

[image]

In Latex code, this is:

```
\subsection{Lineares Positioniersystem mit Waage und 3D-Lasertriangulationssensor}
```

and my toc setup is the following:

```
\usepackage{interfaces}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\tocsetup{
    title/font = \huge\color{blue},
    chapter/number/after = .,
    chapter/number/width=8mm,   
    section/number/after = .,
    section/indent = 8mm,
    section/number/width=10mm,
    subsection/indent=18mm,
    subsection/number/after = .,
    subsection/number/width=12mm
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this the same document like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418800)? If so, again this issue wouldn't occur if you used the means provided by KOMA to customize your ToC. Also please provide us with a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the described behaviour but doesn't contain anything unrelated to your issue.

Comment: Turns out this is not because of your use of `tocloft` but a simple hyphenation problem. I'll provide an answer.

Comment: For future: Pay attention to the overfull hbox warnings; they would have notified you of the problem and you could have fixed it yourself in one of the usual ways (add hyphenation, rewrite text, increase tolerance and/or emergencystretch, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX tries to put your subsection title inside of the text area, but fails to do so as it doesn't find a good hyphenation point in "3D-Lasertriangulationssensor". This is the fact because by default, words containing a hyphen are not hyphenated on any other spot. The quick solution would be to tell TeX where this word is hyphenatable with `\-`:

```
\subsection{Lineares Positioniersystem mit Waage und 3D-La\-ser\-tri\-an\-gu\-la\-tions\-sen\-sor}
```

A complete document which uses KOMA-script to setup a ToC similar to yours:

```
\documentclass[
        a4paper,
        11pt,
        parskip=half-,
        oneside,
        listof=totoc,
        bibliography=numbered,
        headings=big,
        appendixprefix=true
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\setkomafont{partentry}{\large\bfseries\color{blue}}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocnumwidth=8mm
  ]{part}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocindent=8mm
    ,tocnumwidth=8mm
  ]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocindent=16mm
    ,tocnumwidth=10mm
  ]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocindent=26mm
    ,tocnumwidth=10mm
  ]{subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand
  [%
    ,tocindent=36mm
    ,tocnumwidth=13mm
  ]{subsubsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry
  [%
    numwidth=13mm
  ]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry
  [%
    numwidth=13mm
  ]{tocline}{table}

\BeforeTOCHead{\addtokomafont{chapter}{\huge\color{blue}}}

\begin{document}    
\pagenumbering{Roman}
Some beginning text
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\part{FOOOBAR}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Some Text included by "include commands"
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\Blinddocument
\subsection{Lineares Positioniersystem mit Waage und 3D-La\-ser\-tri\-an\-gu\-la\-tions\-sen\-sor}
\captionof{figure}{foobar}
\captionof{table}{foobar}
\end{document}
```

Resulting ToC:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, does koma also support the setup of lof & lot?

Comment: @the_dani `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[<options>]{<base-style>}{<figure/table>}` would do, in the above I used `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=13mm]{dottedtocline}{table}` for example. Take a look in the scrguide for documentation.

Comment: If the words should not be hyphenated in the TOC,  `tocraggedentrytext` can be added to the settings of `subsection`. Then the entry text for subsections will be right aligned.